# SSRS VLookup possible?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to use VLookup in SSRS ? I know we can use lookups but I want to create a SSRS report with Vlookup then export it to excel ?

If you don't know difference between lookup and Vlookup then, Vlookup works dynamically, e.g. if you enter value in a textbox, it gets results from datasets in the report.

E.g.

TextBox for OrderId :  ______

TextBox for Location :  *****

When user adds a orderId location text box gets updated, and it all happens dynamically.

Comment: SSRS doesn't do dynamically updated text boxes. It's a report tool not an interactive tool. You can use parameters to do something similar to this but with a combo box not a text box. Is that what you're after?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I want to embed excel VLookup formula into SSRS so that when I export the report into excel, our clients would be able to do VLookups

Comment: As far as I know that's not possible. You could export the SSRS report to an Excel file then run some script over to add the VLookup afterwards but that's really over the top.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that trick might work, going to find a tut for it

Comment: You cannot edit a textbox during run time. But it seems like what you're trying to do is a parameter. You can do it in parameters, that is a Cascading parameter -- the value of the other one depends on the other.

Comment: @Kim parameters are useless when I will export my report to excel, won't it be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible with SSRS. SSRS will not let you export Excel formulas.

The closest you may be able to get is to have SSRS export the file to a location then have an SSIS job update your file with the formula you want in a Script Task:

```
...
ExcelFormula = "=SUM(" & SumColumn & "45:" & SumColumn & Row.ToString & ")"
Worksheet.Cells(Row, Column - 1).Formula = ExcelFormula
...
```

http://bidn.com/Blogs/updating-a-single-excel-cell-using-ssis

[Refresh Excel using SSIS script task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796180/refresh-excel-using-ssis-script-task)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403358.aspx